# M 1.9: Data from Block to be passed into phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

In phtml I have a simple form with a submit button.
Upon submit a function within my block is called (via form action) and retrieves data from the db.
How can I send the result back to the phtml or directly into the formfields?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $this->myFunction(); ?>">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

```
 <?php
class Marc_MiniBlog_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    function myFunction() {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

        return($results);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally the form action posts to a certain URL, it can't call a method in a block class. You would need to create an AJAX call for that which means you need to create a controller with a method that executes that query and returns it via javascript.

The controller would look something like

```
class Marc_MiniBlog_PostController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{

    function resultAction() 
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
$this->getResponse()->setBody($results);
    }
}
```

And in your `config.xml` you'd need to add the following

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <miniblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Marc_MiniBlog</module>
                <frontName>miniblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </miniblog>
    </routers>   
</frontend>
```

Now, when calling `http://domain.com/miniblog/post/result/` with AJAX from your form you would get a JSON array with the results back which you can process further